# How can i make a file upload, to another aspx file?

Tags: .net, asp.net

well, i'm working in domain1. I need to upload a file to domain2. in my aspx in domain1 i have (outside the main ):

```
<div id="divCurriculo">
    <form id="frmCurric" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://reports.programacontactosonae.com/uploadcv.aspx" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="284" />
    <table>
        <tr>

            <td class="first">
                <label>Currículo</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="file" id="filecv" style="display:inline-block;" />
                <input type="submit" value="Enviar" style="width:70px;display:inline-block;" />
            </td>       
        <tr>            
    </table>

    </form>
</div>
```

So, what do i need in my receiving file in domain2 to get the file? This is what i have:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      string userid = Request.Form["userid"];
      Response.Write(userid + "<br />"); // i catch, successfully, the value in the hiddenfield

      HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[0];//here i get an error cause it can't find any file
      Response.Write(file.ToString());            
}
```

Comment: Per your comment below; please post the *actual* code you are using on both pages, and share what kind of page you are putting this form in.

Comment: If you have the enctype that should work; what happens?

Comment: when i access Request.Files[0] i get index was outside the bounds of the array, because there is no file

Comment: Andrew, your right, i didn't post the whole code, because that form is sitting in a DynamicWeb platform with lots of trash tags, so i simplified it. I'm sorry i forgot the enctype, but it's there

Comment: We need to see your actual code to figure this out. Your 'trash tags' may be what is causing this.

Comment: well i updated the main question with the exact html rendered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully it's something this simple, but try adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your `form` tag:

```
<form action="www.domain2.com/upload.aspx" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="hiden" id="userid" value="12345" />
   <input type="file" id="curriculo" />
   <input type="submit" id="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: oh, thank you and i'm sorry. I am using enctype, i just forgot to put it in my question...

Comment: Please paste the *actual* code you are using... how else can we help you?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers concerning the missing `enctype` attribute, your code is quite brittle otherwise; you should check to make sure at least one file is present before trying to access the `Request.Files` collection, and display an error message if a file does not exist, letting them know to try again. Otherwise, users who forget to choose a file will get a very unhelpful error message (same one you are seeing now)

Otherwise, I'm going to assume/hope you are properly verifying/cleaning things up security-wise - like not trusting the userid value being submitted, and verifying that the content submitted isn't dangerous.

Comment: thank you, i am. I just put the simplified version of the code here. I am using enctype, i just forgot to put it here too.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are just missing the enctype; on the for
, add an attribute:

```
 <form ...  enctype="multipart/form-data">...
```

Comment: thank you and i'm sorry. I am using enctype, i just forgot to put it in my question..